# C# "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"}

Tags: c#, oracle

First I have searched other posts which I have not found one that matches my issue.

I using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess version 4.122.1.0

my app.config file connectionstring is

```
<add name="connstring1" connectionString="Data Source=NAMEOFTNS;User ID=**UserNAME**;Password=***pass***;" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>


OracleConn = OracleProviderFactory.CreateConnection();
            OracleConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring1"].ConnectionString;
 OracleConn.Open();
```

it is at the  OracleConn.Open(); that I get the error

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I have tested the TNSNAME with TNSPING and it comes back fine.

I can put the connection information from the TNS file and replace the TNSNAME in the connection string with the connection info and it works fine. The issue though is we need this to work by the TNS file so that we only have to update the single file when ever we perform updates with the different severs versus changing all of the app config files for each of our applications.

most suggestions are to bypass the TNS file entirely and put the connection info directly into the app.config file but as mentioned above that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Found my answer, although not specifically using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

instead using Oracle.DataAccess 
found the answer at the link below 
After the OracleCommand instantiation you have to OracleCommand.BindByName = true;

my specific code is

```
OracleCommand oracleCommand = new OracleCommand
        {
            BindByName = true
        };
```

I have to say I am surprised that Oracle requires you to specify to use the TNS file instead of having that as a default

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/code-154692.html

Comment: This answer makes no sense. You said the error happened at connection.Open. So setting the BindByName would happen after that.